next-auth server side session not updating
im using nextjs 14 and nextauth5 for login authentication. client-side session is updating but not in server-side. im trying to change the default session values on next-auth by following their docs (name, email, image).
here's the session data on the web page
webpage
here's my terminal
terminal
auth.ts
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";

import { getUserById } from "./data/user";
import { UserRole } from "@prisma/client";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/db";
import authConfig from "@/auth.config";

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface Session {
        user: {
            fullName: string;
            username: string;
            role: UserRole;
            department: string;
        } & DefaultSession["user"];
    }
}

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
    ...authConfig,
    callbacks: {
        async session({ token, session, user }) {
            console.log({ sessionToken: session });

            if (token.sub && session.user) {
                session.user.id = token.sub;
                session.user.fullName = token.fullName as string;
                session.user.username = token.username as string;
                session.user.role = token.role as UserRole;
                session.user.department = token.department as string;
                
            }
            return session;
        },

        async jwt({ token }) {
            if (!token.sub) return token;

            const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);

            if (!existingUser) return token;

            token.role = existingUser.role;
            token.fullName = existingUser.fullName;
            token.username = existingUser.username;
            token.department = existingUser.department;
            console.log({ Token: token });

            return token;
        },
    },
});

FormsPage.tsx
import { logout } from "@/actions/actions";
import { auth } from "@/auth";

const FormsPage = async () => {
    const session = await auth();

    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <h1>Forms Page</h1>
                <form action={logout}>
                    <button>Logout</button>
                </form>
                {JSON.stringify(session)}
            </section>
        </>
    );
};

export default FormsPage;

does this have something to do with my callbacks?
I've searched lots of post similar to my issue but haven't fixed the issue.

According to the documentation about the session callback, user gets only passed in a database session, otherwise it's the JWT payload (token). Your strategy is jwt, so you've gotta go with the token parameter and its payload. To get the related user information, you can probably access token.username and the alike - values you've set in the JWT payload at the jwt callback.
